# Why is my function not being called on the SignalR hub

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, signalr-hub

I am experimenting with SignalR right now with a simple chat. I am trying to send a message to a user2 if user1 provides user2's userId from Context.ConnectionId. My Client Side code:

```
const sendMessage = async (user, message) => {
    const chatMessage = {
        user: "generic user",
        message: message
    };

    if (connection.connectionStarted) {
        try {
            console.log("user: " + user);
            console.log("message: " + message);
            console.log("message sent");
            await connection.send('SendMessage',user, chatMessage);
        }
        catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
    else {
        alert('No connection to server yet.');
    }
}
```

When I send a message from the client side, I receive the correct console.logs, making me believe that my client side code is fine. However, my Hub server is not receiving my message.

```
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, ChatMessage message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received user:" + user);
        await Clients.Group(user).ReceiveMessage(message);
    }
```

I never get the the user in my console. But I can't figure out why I never get the message.

Comment: `my Hub server is not receiving my message` If you debug the code of hub server, does the hub method `SendMessage` be triggered while you invoke it from your client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Context.ConnectionId` as the "user" value, then you should be using `Clients.Client(user).ReceiveMessage(message);` instead.

`Clients.Group(...)` takes a group name that you've added clients to with `Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);`.